# Can't view Gyro on Galaxy Tab 10

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I installed AndroSensor on S3. I can view all sensors. 
When I installed this software on Galaxy Tab 10. I can't view Gyro sensor data.
I am working on a project where I need to access gyro and accelerometer.

Both phones have Gyro-

- In S3 we have: LSM330DLC
- In Galaxy Tab we have: MPU 3050

Android Versions of the Phones are:

- S3 : Android OS, v4.1
- Galaxy Tab: Android OS, v4.0.3

So is the software not working because of Android Version? or because the data from the sensors is different?

Why is the software not detecting the Gyro on both Phones?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest writing some code to query Android's SensorManager object.  For example, try the following

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(android.content.Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensorlist = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for(Sensor sens : sensorlist) {
    Log.d("TEST", "Name="+sens.getName()+",Type="+sens.getType());
}
Sensor SensorGyro = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
Log.d("TEST", (SensorGyro == null ? "SensorGyro==null":"Name="+SensorGyro.getName()+",Type="+SensorGyro.getType()));
```

and use the output to help work out what's going wrong.  I ran that on my Galaxy note 2 and it produced:

```
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor,Type=1
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=AK8963C Magnetic field Sensor,Type=2
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=LSM330DLC Gyroscope Sensor,Type=4
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=BMP182 Barometer Sensor,Type=6
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=CM36651 Proximity Sensor,Type=8
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=CM36651 Light Sensor,Type=5
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=Rotation Vector Sensor,Type=11
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=Gravity Sensor,Type=9
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=Linear Acceleration Sensor,Type=10
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=Orientation Sensor,Type=3
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=Corrected Gyroscope Sensor,Type=4
05-07 14:42:38.585: D/TEST(6160): Name=LSM330DLC Gyroscope Sensor,Type=4
```

so there appear to be two Gysoscope sensors on that phone.